# getting size of an array from memberfunction

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project where I need to declare a std::array as a private variable in a class, but the size of this array should be returned from a memberfunction called **getNumberOfStudents()**.
Do you have any idea how could I solve this problem?
I will appreciate your help.

```
class Student{
private:
std::array<int,getNumberOfStudents()> arr;

public:
 int getNumberOfStudents(){
       std::cout<<"How many students do you wanna add? ";
       std::cin>>numberOfStudent;
       return numberOfStudent;
   }
};
```

Comment: thats not possible, why do you need it? the size of the array must be known at compile time.

Comment: are you looking for `std::vector` ?

Comment: btw a `Student` should not be an `ArrayOfStudents`. The method is like asking a single student: "How many are you?"

Comment: You cannot read a `std::array`s size at runtime from user input. There are other ways, but `std::vector` is the most straightforward

Comment: Well, I asked firstly how many students are there and stored their name in a vector and now I'm trying to ask every student how many courses does he enroll, so I will store the number of courses in an array/vector. For this reason I thought, there is an another opportunity than std::vector like an array.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number okay, then I will use a vector again. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Apart from the above, you try to initialise a `Student`, class member, `arr`, during construction _with a non-static member function_ `getNumberOfStudents()`. But member functions are bound to a fully constructed instance, and thus can only be invoked on a fully constructed instance`. Chicken and egg.